# Kotlin field overriding and GSON deserialization Unable to create converter class exception

Tags: android, serialization, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I have a parent class in `Kotlin` like this

```
open class Prescription(
open var name: String,
open val id: String,
open var dose: JsonElement?,
open var schedule: JsonElement?,
open var notes: String?,
@SerializedName("as_needed")
open var isAsNeeded: Boolean,
open var archiveDate: Long?) {
constructor(name: String, dose: JsonElement?, schedule: JsonElement?, isAsNeeded: Boolean, notes: String?)
    : this(
    id = name.toLowerCase() + "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().subSequence(0, 6),
    name = name,
    dose = dose,
    schedule = schedule,
    isAsNeeded = isAsNeeded,
    archiveDate = null,
    notes = notes
)
}
```

And a child class like this

```
class Medication(
    override var name: String,
    override var dose: JsonElement?,
    override var schedule: JsonElement?,
    override var isAsNeeded: Boolean,
    override var notes: String?,
    override var id: String,
    val other: String?,
) : Topic, Prescription(
    name = name,
    dose = dose,
    schedule = schedule,
    isAsNeeded = isAsNeeded,
    notes = notes
)
```

when I am trying to deserialize `Medication` class with `GSON` I get `IllegalArgumentException` saying that `Medication` class `declares multiple JSON fields named dose.` I am not sure how fields are duplicating when `override` is added to fields. What would be correct way of doing this in `Kotlin` + `GSON`

Comment: `override var isAsNeeded: Boolean,` why are you doing this ??

you can simply use  `isAsNeeded: Boolean` and pass it to `Prescription` constructor

Comment: okay, whats the point of inheriting `Prescription` then? I can simply create a different model as well!

Comment: that is your use case you might need the same variable's in multiple class.

you can override later on while using the variable not while parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Medication(
     name: String,
     dose: JsonElement?,
     schedule: JsonElement?,
     isAsNeeded: Boolean,
     notes: String?,
     id: String,
     val other: String?,
) : Topic, Prescription(
    name,
    dose,
    schedule,
    isAsNeeded,
    notes
)
```

*try above... in `Medication` class there is no need of overriding the variable.*

As name,
    dose,
    schedule,
    isAsNeeded,
    notes
are already declared in the super class there is no need of overriding you can directly use them.

```
open class Prescription(
protected var name: String,
protected val id: String,
protected var dose: JsonElement?,
protected var schedule: JsonElement?,
protected var notes: String?,
@SerializedName("as_needed")
protected var isAsNeeded: Boolean,
protected var archiveDate: Long?) {
constructor(name: String, dose: JsonElement?, schedule: JsonElement?, isAsNeeded: Boolean, notes: String?)
    : this(
    id = name.toLowerCase() + "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().subSequence(0, 6),
    name = name,
    dose = dose,
    schedule = schedule,
    isAsNeeded = isAsNeeded,
    archiveDate = null,
    notes = notes
)
}
```

And i believe keeping your var/val protected in your super class is more preferable.

Comment: my bad i was using `val` in child class